# How to calculate amount by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

As u can see i have this form that calculate number of employees multiply by test that will be select by user. number of employees will be input by user and test are coming from database. each test have their individual price set in database. I used script for dropdown list.

If user put any value in no.of employees and check on anytest then in total amount sum should be calculate onclick buytest?

```
<form action="add_corporate_test.php" method="POST">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example-onDeselectAll').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                onDeselectAll: function () {
                    alert('please select any test!');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="row">
        <h5 class="cor_label">No. of Emp/Students:</h5>
        <input
            type="text" id="no_emp"
            placeholder="No. of Employees/Students"
            class="normal" required
        >
        <h5 class="cor_label">Email Address:</h5>
        <input
            type="text"
            id="no_emp2"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            class="normal" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[email]; ?>"
            required
            disabled
        >
        <h5 class="cor_label">Select Test:</h5>
        <select id="example-onDeselectAll" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from `test` ");
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                $sum = 0;
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['test_name']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $data['test_name']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <h5 class="cor_label">Total Amount:</h5>
        <input
            type="text"
            id="no_emp3"
            class="normal"
            name="total_amount"
            placeholder="total amount"
            value="<?php echo $sum; ?>"
            disabled
        >
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="corporate_buy">
            Buy Test
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi bro, use for loop for script b'coz u have multiple select option
>   `

```
<script>
$('#example-onDeselectAll').change(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
var i=0; 
var len = value.length;
var no_emp = $("#no_emp").val();
  for(i; i < len; i++){
var res = value[i] .split("_");
var tot_amount += res[1]*no_emp;
}
$("#no_emp3").val(tot_amount);
});
</scrit>
```

`

Comment: I cant get my error. onclick buy test it shows 0 n refresh the page. If user put any value in total employees and select any test the field of total amount should be give amount without onclick or something.

Comment: http://www.adtest.adnacgroup.com/newadtestplus/organization_home.php this is my lin id= aa@aa.com pass=123

Comment: <script>
 $("#no_emp3").val(0); 
 $('.mul').click(function()
 {
  //alert($(this).val());
  var no_emp = $("#no_emp").val();  
  var no_emp2 =$(this).val();  
  var tot_amount = parseInt(no_emp) * parseInt(no_emp2) ;  
  var t=$("#no_emp3").val();
  $("#no_emp3").val(tot_amount)+(t);  
 });
</script> this is code is working for me bro. but it takes only 1 chechbox value . if i want multiple to be calculate wts the solution

Comment: use 'for loop' for your on click event bro

Answer (score 1):

> get the test and value on select option. on select split the value using javascript. and then sum the amount and no.of.employee

`

```
<select id="example-onDeselectAll" multiple="multiple" >
            <?php   
                    $sql=mysql_query("select * from `test` ");
                while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
                {
                    $sum=0; 
                ?>                                  
               <option  value="<?php echo $data['test_name'];?>_<?php echo $data['price'];?>"><?php echo $data['test_name'];?></option>                             
            <?php }?>                     
            </select>  

<script>
$('#example-onDeselectAll').change(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
var no_emp = $("#no_emp").val();
var res = value .split("_");
var tot_amount = res[1]*no_emp;
$("#no_emp3").val(tot_amount);
});
</scrit>
```

`

Comment: Why not add a data or rel??

Comment: .thanks for help bro i used your code but its now working for me. total amount is still showing o value.

Comment: Hi, bro alert the tot_amount value. If u not get the answer, some issue for getting variable value

Comment: On alert tot_amount nothing happens. onclick buy test it goes to form action and redirect on same page.

Comment: don't right script instead of form. Put a script for after the form. And why u use multi select option